# Change all the values of a data frame based on conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to change the values of a data frame based on different conditions in python.

Here is an example of my dataset

`df1=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A',1, 2, 'NaN'], ['B',-4, 5, -6], ['C',7, 0, 9]]), columns=['Details','a', 'b', 'c'])`

and i want to change the values as follwoing,

`df1=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A','big', 'big', 'No data'], ['B','small', 'big', 'small'], ['C','big', 'zero', 'big']]),columns=['Details','a', 'b', 'c'])`

I have tried using the following line but this did not work. I am wondering if there is any easy way to do this. thanks in advance

`df1[df1.columns[1:]] = df1.iloc[:,1:].where(df1.iloc[:,1:] >0 ,'big')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) only for selected columns:

```
c = ['a','b','c']

#if necessary convert to numeric
df1[c] = df1[c].astype(float)

df1[c] = np.select([df1[c] > 0, df1[c] <= 0], ['big','small'], default='No data') 
print (df1)
  Details      a      b        c
0       A    big    big  No data
1       B  small    big    small
2       C    big  small      big
```

If need test all columns without first:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = np.select([df1.iloc[:, 1:] > 0, 
                             df1.iloc[:, 1:] <= 0], ['big','small'], default='No data')
```

Comment: @Monica - Do you convert columns to floats? `df1[c] = df1[c].astype(float)` ? And for second solution `df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float)` before `np.select`